# Passing parameter to javascript function in an Ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i am calling this UpdateItem function using ajax, using achor tag .
it gave me console error

Error : **req is undefined**

```
 function updateItem(id, desc, vehicleno){
         alert("i am here");
         $('#ProcessModal').modal('show');
         $('#<%=txtPartNo.ClientID%>')[0].value=id;
        $('#<%=txtPartNo.ClientID%>')[0].value=partno;
    }
```

Ajax calling ...

```
     ......
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "<%=BasePath%>/WebServices/RequisitionService.asmx/GetAllRequisitionItems",
             data: '{ ReqID: "<%=_RecordId%>"}',
             dataType: "json",                         
             success: function (data) {       
                 var req=[];
                 var desc=[];
                 var veh=[];

                 for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                      req[i] =data.d[i].RequisitionItemsID;
                       desc[i]= data.d[i].ItemDescription;
                       veh[i]= data.d[i].VehicleNumber;
                     $("#reqTable").append("<tr><td>"+data.d[i].PartNo  + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].ItemDescription +"</td><td>"+data.d[i].Quantity+"</td><td>"+data.d[i].VehicleNumber+"</td><td> " + data.d[i].ItemStatus +"</td><td>"+ data.d[i].Remarks+"</td><td><a href='javascript:updateItem(req[i], desc[i], veh[i] );'>Process</a> </td></tr>");
                }    
            },
             error: function (result) {                         
             },
         });
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its quite easy , you have done nothing wrong except the quotation marks..
kindly correct them as follow , it will work.

At declaration:

```
var req='';
var desc='';
ar veh='';
```

and in your function where you require these variables.

```
<a href='javascript:updateItem(\"" + req + "\", \"" + desc + "\",\"" + veh + "\" );' <%= (ReqStage == (int)RequisitionStage.PendingforHOApproval) ? "" : "style=display:none"  %>>Process</a> </td></tr>");
```

Hope it helps
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript Array push() Method. Like -

```
req.push(data.d[i].RequisitionItemsID);
desc.push(data.d[i].ItemDescription);
veh.push(data.d[i].VehicleNumber);
```